# Geonames API, using while() for getting names of countries

Tags: php, api, while-loop, geonames

I need to get all countries with geonames api. I can use `$geonames->genomes[2]->countryName` to get country name of 2nd. But I want it auto like `while()` how can I use it with `while()` in php?

JSON IS HERE
`{"geonames":[{"countryName":"Andorra","currencyCode":"EUR","fipsCode":"AN","countryCode":"AD","isoNumeric":"020","north":42.65604389629997,"capital":"Andorra la Vella","continentName":"Europe","areaInSqKm":"468.0","languages":"ca","isoAlpha3":"AND","continent":"EU","south":42.42849259876837,"east":1.7865427778319827,"geonameId":3041565,"west":1.4071867141112762,"population":"84000"},{"countryName":"United Arab Emirates","currencyCode":"AED","fipsCode":"AE","countryCode":"AE","isoNumeric":"784","north":26.08415985107422,"capital":"Abu Dhabi","continentName":"Asia","areaInSqKm":"82880.0","languages":"ar-AE,fa,en,hi,ur","isoAlpha3":"ARE","continent":"AS","south":22.633329391479492,"east":56.38166046142578,"geonameId":290557,"west":51.58332824707031,"population":"4975593"}]}`

Comment: i once did something like this using yahoo geo services , please check the link ,,, i hope it helps u :  https://github.com/leo086/yahoo_WOEID

Comment: oh that one is good too! I'll check it out because geonames has limit.

Answer (score 1):

We have a CSV file that has all the countries in the world, their corresponding ISO codes, and their short and formal names in English, French, Spanish, Russian, Chinese, Arabic, and Italian. This was compiled from various government and international references:

http://www.opengeocode.org/download/countrynames.txt

References are cited at:

http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#countrynames

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numCountries; $i++) {
  echo $geonames->geonames[$i]->countryName;
}
```

Comment: but how to get number of countries then?

Comment: Anyway found count($geonames->genomes);